# How do I output text to an aggregated formula in google data studio?

Tags: google-data-studio

I have a problem with the formula below in Google Data Studio.

[image]

As you can see it did not perform correctly, it should return the boxed value as "TRUE".

[image]

The problem I think is because of the aggregated data combined with the text but I have no idea how to solve it since I am new to google data studio, I have tried searching but no luck. I would appreciate if you could send me instruction on how to deal with this. Thanks

[image]